# Android unit test - how to test multiple activities

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to test multiple activities in the same test project

I don't want all the testing classes to run, only the one i am testing

what do I need to configure to make that happen ?

Is it possible to determine only certain methods in a class run , and not all of them?

Is it possible to determine the order of the methods that will run in the test case ?

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply create a "test bench" activity.  In TestBench, you have a list of buttons.  Each button launches the activity you wish to test.

Within an activity, you only have marginal indirect control of what callbacks happen.  For example, onClick will happen when you click a button or some other registered widget.  Sometimes for debugging callbacks I find the best way is to put in lots of System.out.println (or log) calls.